# How do I watermark an Android app?

Tags: android, watermark

I would like to distribute my app to a group of beta testers but would like to watermark specific version (APK?) to each tester. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: you mean watermark for all your images?

Comment: @Macarse I assume he means embed identifying information in each distribution package to tell which tester redistributes it.

Comment: no, I mean marketing the actual version each one of the testers get so i know no one will share it with others. It's a security measurements before releasing a new version.

Thanks.

Comment: @meagar that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest attribute set the `android:versionCode` to a different number for each build. Easy and visible from settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a int version in your activity and build your apk.

change the int for each build...

If your app is using an server api to retrieve information, make sure so add this version to all api-requests... if version-number is out of scope, make a response that closes the app.